# Trouble getting a response from an asp.NET WebAPI in an Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to add a ASP.NET Web API ( from MVC 4 ) to my project.....  But I'm having some trouble getting any response from the Area/WebAPI/Controller  ( not quite sure where it's going wrong...)

I installed the Route Debugger, and if I go to my main page... I see the routes...

```
Matches Current Request Url Defaults    Constraints DataTokens


    False   api/{controller}/{action}/{id}  action = Index, id = UrlParameter.Optional  (empty) Namespaces = OutpostBusinessWeb.Areas.api.*, area = api, UseNamespaceFallback = False
    False   {resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}  (null)  (empty) (null)
    True    {controller}/{action}/{id}  controller = Home, action = Index, id = UrlParameter.Optional   (empty) (empty)
    True    {*catchall} (null)  (null)  (null)
```

So it seems like the route is setup

Next I have a PlansController in the "api" Area,   It's just the default apiController generated by "Add New"...

```
public class PlansController : ApiController
{
    // GET /api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET /api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST /api/<controller>
    public void Post(string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT /api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE /api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Now When I go to `http://localhost:2307/api/Plans/1`

I get

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.    
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
    Requested URL: /api/Plans/1
```

Any ideas why?  Is there something I need to configure?

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC 4 doesn't support WebApi in areas out of the box.

Martin Devillers proposed a solution: [ASP.NET MVC 4 RC: Getting WebApi and Areas to play nicely](http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/)

You can also have more details in my response on a similar question (especially for support with portable areas):
[ASP.Net WebAPI area support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074117/asp-new-webapi-area-support/11527910#11527910)

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
    // GET /api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> GetMultiple(int id)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Call it with:

http://localhost:2307/api/Plans/GetMultiple/1

This is my Global.asax:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My Controller:

```
   public class MyApiController : ApiController
   {
      public IQueryable<MyEntityDto> Lookup(string id) {

        ..
   }
```

I called it as follows:

```
    http://localhost/MyWebsite/api/MyApi/Lookup/hello
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: sorry, I didn't include the full source....  the default implementation does have a method for get(int id)

Comment: what if you put it in an area?