# ASP.Net WebAPI area support

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to add  some WebAPI support to my asp.net 4 RC site, and wish to put it into an area.  I have seen that someone managed to get this running on the beta ([here](http://netmvc.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html)) , but to be honest, have no idea what I am doing in the RC.

Has anybody managed to add area support to the RC of WebAPI?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can put Api controllers in any folder you like, you don't need to create an Area like you did for MVC. What I usually do is create a subfolder 'Api' inside 'Controllers' folder of MVC site. Just register routes for your Api controllers and it will work.

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out that noth!ing of mine was working because I registered my /api/ route after the default route, which was capturing all api calls

Comment: Can i have 2 Global.asax for both WebAPI and asp.net 4 site?

Comment: Having two controller with the same name is not allowed whereas it is possible with ASP MVC Areas. Also you should add a constraint on {controller} so your route map only to controller in a specific namespace (if you make an API route per 'area'). I built a nuget package to generate automatically the constraints and eventually allow controllers with same name. https://www.nuget.org/packages/UsefulBits.Web.Http.Areas/

Answer (score 24):

**Supporting areas in the web API URLs**

You simply have to register the Web API route.

But this route must be registered before the other routes. If not, the requests to the web API will be mistakenly handled as if they were an MVC action.

When you're using areas, you must take into account that the registration for the areas routes is usually done before the registration of the non-area routes. I.e, in `Global.asax Application_Start` you have these lines of code, in this order:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
// ...
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

The first method call will invoke the `RegisterArea` method of every found `xxxAreaRegistration` class. And, inside this configuration you'll usually have something like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "AreaName_default",
    "AreaName/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If you want to have Web API controllers inside this area, you must add the Web API route before this one, like so:

```
context.Routes.MapHttpRoute("AreaName_WebApiRoute",
    "AreaName/Api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

In this case, I'm assuming that you want to invoke your API controllers using an url like this: `/AreaName/Api/ControllerName/Id`.

I usually store the Web API controllers inside an `Api` folder inside the area folder, but it doesn't matter where you put them. Take into account that the API controllers will be found wherever they are and, if you use the same name for them in different areas, you'll get conflicts: they're found by the class name, not by the fully qualified (namespaced) name.

In few words: there's no real support for areas, but you can include them in their own folders inside the areas, and make them available on URL's which look like the ones of MVC controllers inside areas.

**Supporting route namespaces**

What if you want to have Web API controllers with the same name in different areas? If you really want to give real support for areas to Web API controllers, you have to implement and register a custom [IHttpControllerSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886197/what-is-the-equivalent-of-defaultcontrollerfactory-in-asp-net-web-api).

You have a good explanation, and a sample implementation here: [ASP.NET Web API: Using Namespaces to Version Web APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/03/07/asp-net-web-api-using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis/)

This sample uses namespaces for versioning, but the code can be slightly modified to support areas namespaces.

Answer (score 13):

ASP.NET MVC 4 doesn't support WebAPI in Areas.

It is possible to extend `DefaultHttpControllerSelector` to do this, but you should carefully read this excellent (and short) article: [ASP.NET MVC 4 RC: Getting WebApi and Areas to play nicely](http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/). It works great.

I've successfully tested this solution with portable areas ([MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/)).
Basically, you have to:

- Put extension methods "AreaRegistrationContextExtensions" in the PA project (required from `PortableAreaRegistration.RegisterArea()` method): you can copy the static class into the PA project but I suggest to put it into a shared project.
- Add the class "AreaHttpControllerSelector" (inherited from `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`) into the host project.
- Add to Global.asax App_Start() the following line:

  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new AreaHttpControllerSelector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));

There is one caveat with the implementation of `AreaHttpControllerSelector`: the area name must correspond to the ApiController's namespace. For example, this is my `PortableAreaRegistration` class:

```
namespace PortableAreasSample.MembershipArea
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using MvcContrib.PortableAreas;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Routing;

    public class MembershipRegistration : PortableAreaRegistration
    {
        public override void RegisterArea(System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext context, IApplicationBus bus)
        {
            // GET /MembershipArea/GetAllUsers
            context.MapHttpRoute("MembershipApi",
                AreaName + "/{controller}/{id}",
                new { area=AreaName, controller = "GetAllUsers", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        }

        public override string AreaName
        {
            get { return "MembershipArea"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you register the API route before the default route, else the default route will greedily capture everything!

Answer (score 2):

Just for completion, the following attributes exists, which could help people out of a bind (who won't follow eric's advice above...)

```
[Route ("api/interesting/{id?}")]
[RoutePrefix("api/interesting")]
```

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 0):

In the RegisterArea method inside YourAreaName_AreaRegistration class just register API also so that you can access API

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Your_ProjectName.Areas.YourAreaName
{
    public class YourAreaNameAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "YourAreaName";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.Routes.MapHttpRoute("YourAreaName_WebApiRoute",
                "Api/YourAreaName/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
            
            context.MapRoute(
                "YourAreaName_default",
                "YourAreaName/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
}
```