# What is the equivalent of DefaultControllerFactory in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

We are trying to replace previous DefaultControllerFactory with new ASP.NET Web API to better handle REST/XML calls. Searching the web always pointed to implementating `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver` and then handling the `GetService()` and few other methods required by the interface.

However it seems to be caching the ApiController instance and any new controller, it does not seem to be resolving. Its difficult to provide all possible ApiController instances during startup due to performance issues.

`DefaultControllerFactory` allows providing controller instances and caches the "hit" entries, but throws errors when the an instane could not be delay loaded.

**Are there are other overloads/controller factory methods that requires to be implemented?**

Search did not yield any hits so far, but any pointers will be great. Thank you for your time.

Comment: DefaultControllerFactory is from beta, not in RC anymore, please could you elaborate more "to better handle REST/XML call? what you want to handle?

Comment: Using the default controller factory, a controller is loaded dynamically on demand. This controller has methods to service both xml/json formats using different API (has suffixes json or xml). Managing the equivalents which is essentially doing the same is becoming a problem. Web API seems to be taking care of the media formats and we want to move them into this model, but loading the controller dynamically seems to be a issue.

Comment: if you want to utilize json/xsml suffixes, why not leverage on UriPathExtensionMapping?

Comment: This is looking good, helps a lot of mapping head-ache. Where possible, we have changed it to use this mechanism. Have marked it as an answer too.

Answer (score 10):

<s>It is `IHttpControllerActivator` implemented by `DefaultHttpControllerActivator`.</s>

You may replaces it using:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), 
        new MyOwnActivatior());
```

## Oops!

I meant `IHttpControllerSelector`!

---

It is `IHttpControllerSelector` implemented by `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`.

You may replaces it using:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), 
        new MyOwnActivatior());
```

Comment: Thank you. This works if the controller exists in the assembly. However, we have a need to dynamically load the controller depending on the request made. In this case, call does not come into the controller activator. For example. http://localhost:9999/api/customapi/get/1 works if a type with name "CustomAPIController" exists in the assembly. However, http://localhost:9999/api/customapidynamic1/get/1 does not seem to call Create( ) method of the controller activator. Intended use is to find the load the controller type on demand.

Comment: Then you may need to replace one or more of the following: IHttpControllerSelector (selects the controller), IHttpControllerTypeResolver (provides the list of controller types to IHttpControllerSelector), IAssembliesResolver (provides the list of assemblies). See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

Comment: Thank you MikeWasson. Will try more of these interfaces. Wish it hadn't been this hard.

Comment: Oops!
I meant IHttpControllerSelector!

Comment: @MikeWasson Tried all, but the controller selector is never called, no matter what is done if the controller assembly is loaded dynamically. Trying to fiddle around with url/path variables to see if the call can be forwarded to an internal controller manually. Its ugly, if it works, nothing like it.

Comment: You replaced HttpControllerSelector with a custom implementation and the SelectController method is never called?

Comment: I'm glad you put a strike-through on your previous answer as it was the correct answer to my problem :)