# Accessing an API in an Area of an ASP.Net MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have created an Area called "Jobs" within my Web site. In the Jobs area I have created an ApiController called "Cards". I am trying to access the area and Api with the following url:

> http://example.com/jobs/api/cards/get

But this doesn't seem to find it. What would the route be when the api controller is located in an area?

Comment: I haven't used areas in a while, but I know that you have to register your areas in App_Start. Have you done that?

Comment: There is an AreaRegistration file that takes care of that in each "area"

Comment: How is the route currently defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net WebAPI area support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074117/asp-net-webapi-area-support)