# Web API Attribute Routing in MVC area not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have an existing MVC project. I added a new area and this area will be web api. My web api routes are not being hit and since routing is still a frustrating thing for me I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

In my route provider I thought this was all I had to do...

```
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

In my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/nav")]
public partial class NavigationController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("MainDash")]
   public DashboardModel GetDashItems()
   { ...}
}
```

My MVC area is defined as MyArea,

So in fiddler the following Get request return 404.

```
/MyArea/api/nav/MainDash

/api/nav/MainDash
```

Do I still have to define old fashioned conventional routes as well?

When I register my route I do set a default template...but the attribute routing should override...???

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
   context.MapRoute(
   "MyArea_default",
   "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new {controller="Home", action = "Index", area = "MyArea", id = "" },
   new[] { "Testing.Nav.Controllers" }
        );
}
```

I really don't think this has anything to do with it but I am at a loss for getting my routes figured out.

TIA

---

Update

Forgot this controller is also NOT in the controllers folder. It is in a folder called Api.

I tried /api/api/nav/GetDashIyems but still didn't work. But I wonder do I need to add the Api folder to the route table as an area to search...???

Comment: It looks like you are showing us the MVC routing and have enabled _MVC_ attribute routing. The WebAPI routing configuration is a little different. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2. Notice `.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` vs `.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net WebAPI area support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074117/asp-net-webapi-area-support)

Comment: As was pointed out by Jasen, MVC and WebApi are 2 separate things. WebApi doesn't officially support Areas, but you can adjust your routes and organize your controllers similarly to make it act like it is using Areas. However, you need to configure routing for WebApi first (which you have not yet done). See the link I posted and the one Jasen posted.