# MapHttpAttributeRoutes not working with areas - every route 404s

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm completely stuck on this - after commenting out almost everything to do with startup configuration leaving only the following, I *still* can't get the WebApi Attribute routing to work correctly.

I have the following Global.asax.cs:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

The following controller - located in an area called "v2":

```
[RoutePrefix("v2/businesses")]
public class BusinessesController : ApiController
{
    // GET: v2/businesses/{id}
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public ApiResponse<ApiBusiness> Index(int id)
    {

        return new ApiResponse<ApiBusiness>(new ApiBusiness());

    }
}
```

The following area registration:

```
public class V2AreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "v2";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

And the following WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

When I try to access the endpoint URL `businesses/1` or `v2/businesses/1` or `v2/v2/businesses/1` all three return a 404, I was sure one of those would be correct.

Note that a different controller outside of the "v2" area works perfectly fine:

```
[RoutePrefix("abc")]
public class TestingController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("123")]
    public int Test()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Sure enough, 2 is returned when I access that endpoint (`abc/123`).

Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

Comment: In your case isn't it `v2/v2/businesses/1`?

Comment: I should mention I tried all three, just to be sure I wasn't misunderstanding it. (Question updated to include the third variation).

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you are saying that "v2" is both and mvc route AND a web api route; they can't coexist. 
I mean, they can, but what happens here is that the requests to the web API will be mistakenly handled as if they were an MVC action. That's why you get a 404.

In less words, Web API doesn't really support areas. What you can do here is try to register the web api routing *before* the mvc routing or explicitly handle the web api rounting using `MapHttpRoute`. For example:

```
context.Routes.MapHttpRoute("AreaName_WebApiRoute",
    "AreaName/Api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074117/asp-net-webapi-area-support) SO answer for more details!

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I think there's something else going on here. I completely removed the whole "AreaRegistration" altogether and I'm still having no luck. My goal is to have all controllers routed to using the attributes, and remove all of the convention-based routing.

Comment: To clarify on the above: I have removed ALL MVC routing from the project, the only route-related code now is the call into `MapHttpAttributeRoutes`.

Comment: So you're saying that calling website/api/abc/123 is not working now? Event without all the mvc stuff?

Comment: Nope, nothing I did could make it work. I ended up starting a new Web Api project from scratch.