# Autofac failing to pickup in Web API and OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

I'm trying to setup a project that uses both MVC and Web API via OWIN and I'm having trouble getting Autofac to take a effect.

Here's how I'm initializing Web API:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureWebApi(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = BuildHttpConfiguration();

        var container = AutoFacConfig.BuildContainer();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private static HttpConfiguration BuildHttpConfiguration()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Response formatter config
        config.Formatters.Remove(
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        // Setup Web API error reporting
        var customErrors = (CustomErrorsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");

        IncludeErrorDetailPolicy errorDetailPolicy;

        switch (customErrors.Mode)
        {
            case CustomErrorsMode.RemoteOnly:
                errorDetailPolicy
                    = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.LocalOnly;
                break;
            case CustomErrorsMode.On:
                errorDetailPolicy
                    = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Never;
                break;
            case CustomErrorsMode.Off:
                errorDetailPolicy
                    = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = errorDetailPolicy;

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        SwaggerConfig.ConfigureSwagger(config);

        return config;
    }
}
```

The `BuildContainer()` method looks like the following. This method is used to build the container for both MVC and Web API:

```
public static IContainer BuildContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // Register your MVC controllers.
    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
        .PropertiesAutowired();

    builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

    // OPTIONAL: Register model binders that require DI.
    builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

    // OPTIONAL: Register web abstractions like HttpContextBase.
    builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

    // OPTIONAL: Enable property injection in view pages.
    builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());

    // OPTIONAL: Enable property injection into action filters.
    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

    // Bind the core types
    Core.Infrastructure.AutoFacConfig.BuildContainer(builder);

    builder.RegisterType<Postal.EmailService>().As<Postal.IEmailService>();

    // Effectively auto-wires the anything with an interface within Web assembly infrastructure folder
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IJwtHelper).Assembly)
        .Where(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("MyApp.Web.Infrastructure") && t.GetInterfaces().Any())
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
    return builder.Build();
}
```

I have Web API controllers setup in an area and I had everything working with standard MVC controllers. I would like to use Web API controllers for where it's appropriate, but every time I try to request a controller based on `ApiController` I get the error:

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'XxxController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

-- Edit --

The API area config looks like the following. (Side note: I know this isn't the "proper" way to configure Web API. I include the `{action}` because I feel there are too many controller files otherwise.)

```
public class ApiAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "Api"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Api_default",
            "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }

}
```

The authentication controller looks like this:

```
public class AuthenticationController : MyAppApiJwtController
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly IAppSettingsHelper _appSettingsHelper;
    private readonly IJwtHelper _jwtHelper;
    private readonly IDeviceRepository _deviceRepository;
    private readonly IINLDataService _inlDataService;

    public AuthenticationController(IUserRepository userRepository, IAppSettingsHelper appSettingsHelper, IJwtHelper jwtHelper, IDeviceRepository deviceRepository, IINLDataService inlDataService)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _appSettingsHelper = appSettingsHelper;
        _jwtHelper = jwtHelper;
        _deviceRepository = deviceRepository;
        _inlDataService = inlDataService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public LoginResponseModel Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `MyAppApiJwtController` looks like this:

```
public class MyAppApiJwtController : ApiController
{
    internal IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get { return Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }

    private JwtUserIdentity _currentJwtUser;
    public JwtUserIdentity CurrentJwtUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentJwtUser != null)
                return _currentJwtUser;

            if (User == null)
                return null;

            _currentJwtUser = new JwtUserIdentity((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity);

            return _currentJwtUser;
        }

    }
}
```

-- Edit 2 --

The URL I'm attempting to use is http://localhost:20630/api/authentication/login

-- Edit 3 --

The MVC configuration looks like the following. This is called just before the Web API configuration:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureMvc()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        MvcConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        MvcConfig.ValueConfig();

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AutomapperConfig.Configure();
        JsonConfig.Configure();

        AutoFacConfig.ConfigureContainer();

    }
}
```

Comment: What verison of MVC? because OWIN and MVC don't get along well. Works fine for Web API but have been know to cause problems with routes

Comment: The MVC side of things seems to work just fine though

Comment: Ok. cool. that's great.

Comment: Show the controller and route config. I see you are using Attribute routing in your setup. what path is giving the error

Comment: There you go. I'm overriding the `ApiController` class though I doubt that's the issue. I'm doing similarly in the MVC side of things without a problem

Comment: And what url do you call when you get the error

Comment: Right. Based on your code I am not seeing where you register the areas. Did you call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` at any point during setup

Comment: You're correct, I should have shown that part as well. It's part of the MVC configuration section that runs just before the Web API configuration

Comment: I really don't think it's a routing problem, otherwise we'd be seeing a different error. The controller seems to be found but the dependency injection is failing to be hooked up some how

Comment: I agree. I'm still looking to see what it could be. Was trying to rule out all the other possibilities.

Comment: I do not believe that MVC Areas are supported in Web API, especially if you are registering Web API as an OWIN middleware.

Comment: I don't think it's Web API that's the problem. The route is being resolved, it's Autofac that isn't being hooked up properly.

Comment: What's the inner exception of the provided exception? Anyway, the area registration may truly create controllers conflicts in routing, because at the moment the framework will try to map your API controllers into MVC controllers.

Comment: The inner exception is an `System.ArgumentException`, "Type 'XxxController' does not have a default constructor"

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Web API does not support MVC areas by default.
This code:

```
public class ApiAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "Api"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Api_default",
            "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Will instruct the framework to map any route starting with `Api` to MVC controllers, but, at the same time, such controllers exists only for Web API. This conflict directly relates to the exception thrown when the Dependency Resolver tries to create an instance of the controller (the exception message may be misleading).

What could be happening:

1. MVC is executed first, and tries to map your route `api/authentication/login`. This URI matches your `AreaRegistration`, so it will try to route the request to the `AuthenticationController` inside your `Api` area.
2. MVC asks the Dependency Resolver to create an instance of the above controller, that must inherit from `Controller` (that's because we are in the MVC context).
3. The resolver does not have a registration for a MVC Controller that is called `AuthenticationController` (the `AuthenticationController` inherits from `ApiController`), and it returns null (because that's the expected behavior of the `IServiceProvider.GetService` method).
4. MVC then reverts to its default implementation for creating the controller, but finds that `AuthenticationController` class does not have a parameterless constructor. An exception is thrown.

Please try by removing this area declaration: it is not useful (add your `api` prefix inside `RoutePrefix` or `Route` attributes for your controllers/actions) and works only for MVC, while you are defining Web API as an OWIN middleware.

Reference:
[ASP.Net WebAPI area support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074117/asp-net-webapi-area-support)

Comment: Thanks Frederico. I'm going to try simply removing my area declaration and see if that resolves my issue. I just haven't been able to switch back to that part of the project yet. I'll let you know how it goes