# call url apicontroller in mvc ASP.net with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created this webapi in mvc as you can see here :

```
namespace WebUI.Areas.Administrator.Controllers
{
    public class MemberApiController : ApiController
    {
        private IMemberRepository _iMemberRepository;
        private IJobRepository _iJobRepository;
        private IEducationRepository _iEducationRepository;
        // GET: Administrator/Member
        public MemberApiController(IMemberRepository imemberRepository)
        {

            _iMemberRepository = imemberRepository;

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public Member Get(int id)
        {
            return _iMemberRepository.Get().Where(i=>i.Id==id).First();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see my api is created in `administrator area` .but when i call this url `http://localhost:5542/Api/administrator/memberApi?Id=1` .I get this error :

```
 The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Api/administrator/memberApi
```

My api config

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: the `ctor` should be default one, that is can't allow parameters. how come `/Api/administrator/memberApi` is your route?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh i updated the question

Comment: so you see the rquest url is kinda wrong. should look like `/Api/memberApi`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh http://localhost:5542/api/memberapi?id=1

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh it didn't work

Comment: what doesn't work? Working locally here.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh  when i call this : localhost:5542/api/memberapi?id=1

Comment: works for me locally, are you sure the errror isn't somewhere else. The constructor may be?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh yes i am sure ,which url you call exactly ?and what is your route config

Comment: You need to register the route with an area name. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074117/asp-net-webapi-area-support).